Embla Carousel does not work without min-w-full
can someone please help me with this ? Caousel only works if I put min-w-full  to the embla--slide div .
if I am putting w-1/6 because I need to have 6 images per view on the screen. It just stops working at all.
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import useEmblaCarousel from "embla-carousel-react";
import AutoScroll from "embla-carousel-auto-scroll";

const ImageCarousel = () => {
  const images = [
    "carouselimages/image1.jpg",
    "carouselimages/image1.jpg",
    "carouselimages/image1.jpg",
    "carouselimages/image1.jpg",
    "carouselimages/image1.jpg",
    "carouselimages/image1.jpg",
    
  ];

  const options = { loop: true };
  const [emblaRef, emblaApi] = useEmblaCarousel(options, [
    AutoScroll({ delay: 3000, stopOnInteraction: false }) // Adjust delay as needed
  ]);
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const autoScroll = emblaApi?.plugins()?.autoScroll;
    if (!autoScroll) return;

    setIsPlaying(autoScroll.isPlaying());
    emblaApi.on('autoScroll:play', () => setIsPlaying(true));
    emblaApi.on('autoScroll:stop', () => setIsPlaying(false));
  }, [emblaApi]);

  return (
    <div className="embla overflow-hidden w-full" ref={emblaRef}>
      <div className="flex">
        {images.map((src, index) => (
          <div className=" w-1/6" key={index}>
            <img className="w-full h-[500px] object-cover" src={src} alt={`Image ${index + 1}`} />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ImageCarousel;

